# How to find MAC address in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mac-address

I am trying

```
ifconfig | grep HWaddr
```

it gives me output in two lines

```
enp0s31f6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d8:9q:26:7d:34:ff  
wlp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:71:38:53:e9:1p
```

Which one is my MAC address ?

Answer (score 3):

Both. You have two network interfaces, hence the two lines.

- `enp0s31f6` is most probably a wired interface, its MAC is `d8:9q:26:7d:34:ff`,
- `wlp1s0` is a wireless interface, its MAC is `f8:71:38:53:e9:1p`.